# How do I get text to display underneath an <IMG> tag

Tags: html, css

Let's say you have the following HTML:

```
<html>
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <img src="http://www.ps.uci.edu/~tomba/ants/sugar.jpg" width="50" height="37" />
    This is some centered text blah blah blah and blah
</div>
</html>
```

Now you want the text to display under the image, rather than to the right of it.  Let's say for some strange reason you can't change the HTML, only the CSS file.  One thing you can do is add the "display: block" style to the `<img>` tag, however if you do that, the image will no longer be centered in the div which you need.

If I could modify the HTML, I could just put a `<br />` right after the image (though some say a velociraptor will eat you if you use too many br tags).

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not use margin-top to modify the position?

Comment: Cant you wrap the text within a HTMl tag ? say like a `div` or a `p` tag ?

Comment: Was the question edited? When I answered I distinctly remember there being no mention of "display:block"... Oh well, I deleted my original answer. :)

Comment: @JohnP - Can you provide an example?

Comment: No need, user @Shad has already answered your question :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could make the image `display: block;` **and** `margin: 0 auto;`, like so:

```
img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Nice!  This appears to solve everything without fear of pending velociraptor infestation.

Comment: I actually have no idea why this works..  This is actually per CSS spec and not just random browser behavior, right?

Comment: @Mike lol, yes, I see it/use it for fixed width `div`s or other block level elements ALL the time =)

Comment: This trick has now been added to my arsenal of HTML badass-ness..  Thanks!

Comment: @Mike Christensen: "If both 'margin-left' and 'margin-right' are 'auto', their used values are equal. This horizontally centers the element with respect to the edges of the containing block." (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#blockwidth)